# (duplicate?) When pass an object to function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
 var obj = { hi : 'hello' };

 function myFunction( arg ) {
    console.log( arg.hi );
 }

 myFunction( obj );
```

if I call `myFunction`, does javascript engine pass `obj` as reference? or copy?
Also then, how can I see that?

Comment: in javascript all objects are considered as references .. you can able to understand it while cloning one object to another by simply assigning as obj1 = obj2 any change in obj2 will be reflected in obj1 as obj2 will be a reference to obj1

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I solved immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object are passed by reference not by value. 
So you have to be careful in changing the objects inside the functions.

You could see in my snippet here.

```js
var o = {
  'msg': 'Say Hi!'
  };

function myFun(arg) {
  console.log(arg.msg);
  // This should not be accessible
  // from global scope if is a copy
  arg.msg = 'Bye';
}

myFun(o);

// Check what appened
console.log(o.msg);

// It is passed by reference.
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an object - it passes it as a reference (address which points to the particular object). It's gonna be the same object. Any changes applied within the function will affect the object.

In order to make a copy you can use `Object.assign`